# While loop not reading column by column for the given input

Tags: shell

I am working on a shell script for give the disk usage detail. below are the detail

```
#First getting a detail in a variable
duas=$(df -Ph|awk '{printf "%-60s %-40s\n",$1,$5}'|sed 1d|tr "%" " ")

#reading the variable in while loop

while IFS= read -r c1 c2
do
echo First Col: $c1 Second Col: $c2
done < "$duas"
```

Am not getting the value in separate field. Can you advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @codeforester already mentioned, your issue is that you're attempting to get input from a variable using input redirection notation intended for use with a file.

Given the look of your shell script and the tags on your question, I'd suggest the following in plain old POSIX shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

df -Ph |
  awk '{printf "%-60s %-40s\n",$1,$5}' |
  sed 1d |
  tr "%" " " |
while IFS= read -r c1 c2; do
  printf 'First col: %s Secnd col: %s\n' "$c1" "$c2"
done
```

The pipe character you already know. Putting it at the end of the line tells the shell to assume continuation (i.e. you don't need to escape your newline). Since your while loop is only printing output and not populating variables, it should be fine to pipe directly into the `while read`.

Note that you can shorten the pipe that is parsing your `df` output, since both the `sed` and `tr` parts can be embedded into awk:

```
df -Ph |
  awk 'NR>1 {gsub("%"," "); printf "%-60s %-40s\n",$1,$5}' |
while IFS= read ...
```

---

**Update** based on comment...

> I am not getting the output in separate column even if i use the `while IFS= read -r c1 c2 do echo "First Col: $c1 Second Col: $c2" done < <(df -Ph | awk '{printf "%-60s %-40s\n",$1,$5}' | sed 1d | tr "%" " ")`

Yes, that's correct. You are formatting output from `df`, but then you are using `read` which splits fields based on whitespace.  Note:

```
$ df -Ph | awk '{printf "%-60s %s\n",$1,$5}' | sed 1d | tr "%" " " | head -1
/dev/mapper/poutine-root                                     78
$ df -Ph | awk '{printf "%-60s %s\n",$1,$5}' | sed 1d | tr "%" " " | head -1 \
> | while read c1 c2; do echo "$c1 / $c2"; done
/dev/mapper/poutine-root / 78
$ df -Ph | awk '{printf "%-60s %s\n",$1,$5}' | sed 1d | tr "%" " " | head -1 | while IFS= read c1 c2; do echo "$c1 / $c2"; done
/dev/mapper/poutine-root                                     78 /
```

The impact of `IFS= read` is that you don't get your input split between `$c1` and `$c2`. The impact of leaving out `IFS=` is that you lose the formatting on your input data.

If you want your output formatted, I recommend that you control your formatting on your OUTPUT, not on your input. For example:

```
$ df -Ph | sed 1d | \
> while read c1 _ _ _ c2 _; do printf '%-60s %d\n' "$c1" "${c2%\%}"; done
/dev/mapper/poutine-root                                     78
```

Comment: Hi ghoti, i am not getting the output in separate column even if i use the while IFS= read -r c1 c2
do
  echo "First Col: $c1 Second Col: $c2"
done < <(df -Ph | awk '{printf "%-60s %-40s\n",$1,$5}' | sed 1d | tr "%" " ")

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your input redirect `< "$duas"`.  `duas` is a string, and not a file.  You can rewrite your code in Bash with process substitution, this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r c1 c2
do
  echo "First Col: $c1 Second Col: $c2"
done < <(df -Ph | awk '{printf "%-60s %-40s\n",$1,$5}' | sed 1d | tr "%" " ")
```

Comment: You're assuming the OP is running bash. His tag is just "shell", and his code looks like it would work fine in any old POSIX shell. Did you see something I didn't?

Comment: Good point ghoti.  @peermohammed: please confirm which shell you are using.

Comment: Is that any other option to read the input from variable with multiple lines..and am using bash

Comment: Yes, you can use the construct: `< <(printf "%s" "$duas")`.  What shell are you using?

Comment: Yeah  i will try and update. Thanks codeforester and  @ghoti

Comment: Hi Codeforrester , i tried the method as you mentioned < <(printf "%s" "$duas"). but it is not reading the column by column. Can you please advise.i mentioned as while IFS= read -r c1 c2;do echo First $c1 Second $c2; done < <(printf "%s" "$duas")

Comment: It works properly for me.  What does `duas` contain?

Comment: Same value. duas=$(df -Ph |
  awk 'NR>1 {gsub("%"," "); printf "%-60s %-40s\n",$1,$5}')     while IFS= read -r c1 c2  do echo "First Col: $c1 Second Col: $c2"; done < <(printf "%s" "$duas")

Comment: Hi Codeforester, Sorry. I got it..without IFS in while loop am getting the output(means giving input from variable with multiple lines)..Thanks Sir